# Changing the video file attribute without modifying it ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using a ffmpeg script to change the creation date of the file (access to the file) in the meta tag, parameter: creation_time. It's just that the script that I use modifies the entire video file and change the normal parameter, not only that changes the parameters of the file, it still takes several hours.

How to improve it?

```
ffmpeg -i 06.02.2017_PC.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -metadata creation_time="2016-02-06 18:10:27" 06.02.2017_PC2.mp4
pause
```

How to improve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For such metadata alterations, use mp4box instead.